# retrieve data from result array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an array jobs with fields '['patient']['name']', '['User']['name']', and below is result of array..

```
Job: Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Patient] => Array
            (
                [name] => Patient1 User
            )

        [User] => Array
            (
                [name] => Alex Lopes
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Patient] => Array
            (
                [name] => Patient1 Patient
            )

        [User] => Array
            (
                [name] => Mashal Othman
            )

    )
```

and so on

how can i retrieve value form specific index i can't use jobs[0] because i want dynamic value....if any one understand my problem please help me

Comment: How are you doing your find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `array_shift` to grab the first element of the array. Throw that into a loop where you check if the array still contains elements and you should be able to get your data

ex:

```
$arrayCount = count($jobs);
while ($arrayCount > 0) {
   $job = array_shift($jobs);

   // Do your processing here

   $arrayCount = count($jobs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Set::extract` ? More here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::extract